# How can I request an Image from a URL when the Response is 302?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I want to request an image from a url from within my Grails Service method. When I request the image from a url (in this case from Facebook) I get a 302 redirect. After that I request the new URL again. In the second response I get a 403 forbidden.

Here is the Service method that I use:

```
        static queryImageUrl(url, query, MediaType contentType = urlencodedMediaType) {
                if(query instanceof Map) {
                        query = map2query query
                }

                def uri = new URI("${url}?$query")
                def requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()

                def request = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET)

                try {
                        def response = request.execute()
                        def statusCode = response.statusCode
                        log.debug "got reply from $uri with status code $statusCode"
                        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FOUND) {
                                def newUrl = response.connection.responses.getHeaders().Location[0]
                                log.debug "302 redirect to ${newUrl}"
                                return queryImageUrl(newUrl, "")
                        }

                        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
                                return response.body.bytes
                        }
                        else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
                                throw new IllegalAccessError(response.statusCode.toString())
                        }
                } catch(ex) {
                        log.error "Exception while querying $url", ex
                }



                return null

        }
```

**How do I request an image from a url when the responds status is 302?**

**Edit:**

Here are the logs from a image request for a Facebook user:

```
got reply from http://graph.facebook.com/10002342342395/picture?width=200&height=200 with status code 302

302 redirect to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10491179_578345345924700_6665003172531587407_n.jpg?oh=d91657acaf300c3d01042eccc22cf006&oe=543C6E19&__gda__=1415182364_3afb5be4b59d61c4bb2994d2605d2c65

got reply from https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10491179_578563345345924700_666503453451587407_n.jpg?oh=d91657acaf300c3d01042eccc22cf006&oe=543C6E19&__gda__=1415182364_3afb5be4b59d61c4bb2994d2605d2c65? with status code 403
```

My recursive method is called a second time after the first response because of 302 and the second responds reports 403.

Comment: You send a new request to the URL in the 302's response `Location` header. If that needs authentication, you authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem recently. Then found out, that `HTTPBuilder` handles redirects properly:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  new HTTPBuilder( picUrl ).get( contentType:ContentType.BINARY ){ resp, reader ->
    baos << reader 
  }
  persistByteArraySomehow baos.toByteArray()
```

Update:

```
  static queryImageUrl(url, query, MediaType contentType = urlencodedMediaType) {
     if(query instanceof Map) {
        query = map2query query
     }

     def uri = "${url}?$query"
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
     try{
       new HTTPBuilder( uri ).get( contentType:ContentType.BINARY ){ resp, reader ->
         baos << reader 
       }
       baos.toByteArray()
     }finally{
       baos.close()
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post how I have to modify my example?

Comment: see http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/index.html
is also available as maven dep

Comment: `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'`